# error lnk1104 cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-7, kernel32

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and Windows7 64bit.
When I try to build a simple cpp-project I get this error:

> error lnk1104 cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'

Comment: What are your actual project settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have seen this problem somewhere else and it seems an SDK problem, just try to reinstall the windows SDK for windows7 from here:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279

Restart your Visual studio and see. I hope it helps.